# Delphi: System.Net.HttpClient ignore SSL certificate validation (Error getting Server Certificate)

Tags: delphi

I want made a GET request, without validation of SSL certificate.

I have tried to implement ValidateServerCertificateCallback but HTTP client still to raise exception:

> Exception class ENetHTTPCertificateException with message 'Error getting Server Certificate'

My code:

```
procedure OnValidateServerCertificateCallback(const Sender: TObject; const ARequest: TURLRequest; const Certificate: TCertificate; var Accepted: Boolean);
begin
  Accepted := True;
end;

var
  aHTTP: THTTPClient;
begin
  aHTTP:= THTTPClient.Create();
  try
    aHttp.ValidateServerCertificateCallback := OnValidateServerCertificateCallback;
    aHTTP.Get('https://...');
  finally
    aHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Seen this error when the connection is trying to use a protocol the server doesn't support anymore. Make sure the OS is updated and supports TLS 1.1 and 1.2. One ref: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3140245/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-wi